# Is there any difference between a html form and a php form?

Tags: php, html

So I’ve started this project for uni a couple of weeks ago, and we started learning html, css and javascript. I did some pages, forms, js validation etc., but now I’m kinda stuck on php. When I try to look to videos about how to do validation with php, etc., some people put their forms in a php file, while mine is in html file. Is there any difference. I took a look at my friends project and it looks like he has them both, in a html file and in a php file. Is there any difference? Should I have them both in a html file and in a php file?

Sorry the instructions weren’t clear, but it seems like I was wrong from the getgo on what a php file actually is. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “PHP form”. Whether you put your form into a document with the ending .htm(l) or .php, depends first and foremost on whether it is “static”, or whether you need to execute PHP code in there (either to generate parts of the form dynamically, or to pre-fill the form fields with already entered values, in case it needs to be shown again due to validation failures.)

Comment: I think your asking about validation not *form* (if not then its a silly question). Yes validation should be done clientside and serverside, clientside so it does not need post to the server first and serverside because really thats the only place it can be trusted

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please read [ask] and update your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in where you put your `<form>` is that a **.php file may contain PHP code**, while a **.html contains HTML only** :)

In practice that means that you can put PHP code within your HTML markup (it won't be seen by the client). PHP code within .html file wouldn't be executed and would be a piece of regular text.

I usually set all my View files as .php for the sake of using PHP for dynamic generation and accessing the server-side data within it by  and so on.

**As for whether the `<form>` itself is different? No. It's the same HTML code.**

**PS!** I forgot to mention this, it's kinda important. **PHP validation on POST is much more secure**, not only that, but Javascript and HTML validation only are **not secure**. because pure HTML one won't be back-side. Probably javascript or stuff like `required`, `maxlength=""` in an input. Those are **NOT** secure and should always be double checked on the back-side if the validation matters (like passwords, for legal reasons, et cetera.)

To try this out for yourself, you can make a form, open developer tools with F12 and cut out the maxlength, required etc., you'll see that you can submit the form even without valid data. As you can't actually see the back-side PHP code (it's stripped from the file you receive, you get pretty much a simple .html after the PHP is executed), you can't do this with that type of validation.

Answer (score 1):

there are only one html form that can use in php file. means you can use html code in php file. there are no different php form this is only html form using html form you can submit data to database using html post and get method.

refer link for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp